# Flask Dynamic User Input Without Redirecting or Reloading

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, server

I want to set user input as a variable on the same page without reloading.
Is this possible?

I made this simple example to explain my problem.
The page dynamically counts up every second. The user should type in a new multiplier so for example if he types in 3 the page should add 3 every second etc. This should be dynamic and the page should not reload or redirect.

**Here is the html file for my example:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var intervalID = setInterval(update_values,1000);

            function update_values() {
                $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_stuff',

                function(data) {
                    $('#result').text(data.result);
                    console.log(data)
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="update_values();">
        <span id="result"></span>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
        </script>

        <form method="POST">
            <input name="multiplier" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Set multiplier">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And here is the python file for my example:**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
import webbrowser
import time

a = 0
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_stuff', methods = ['GET'])
def stuff():
    global a
    a = a + 1
    return jsonify(result=a)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('template.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app.run()
```

Comment: Flask IO is usefull for this. It's socket IO and flask combined.

Comment: Thank you Flask IO did the trick for me. This tutorial helped a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdSrkkrj3l4&t=144s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST the multiplier to the Webserver, by using POST instead of GET

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var intervalID = setInterval(update_values,1000);

            function update_values() {

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/_stuff',
                    data: $('#myform').serialize(),
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $('#result').text(data);
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });


            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="update_values();">
        <span id="result"></span>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
        </script>

        <form method="POST" id="myform">
            <input name="multiplier" value="1">
            <input type="submit" value="Set multiplier">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
import webbrowser
import time

a = 0
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/_stuff', methods = ['POST'])
def stuff():
    global a

    multiplier = request.form.get('multiplier')
    a = a + multiplier

    return jsonify(result=a)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('template.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    app.run()
```